# TS2551: Property toSpliced does not exist on type Array

Tags: typescript

According to:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSpliced

the method `.toSpliced()` is now available in all major JS platforms. But as you can see here:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.0-beta#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gcgB6YDQyYCe+hAXpgLoCwAUKJLIggEyrxIB0UIAygA4AbAJbAApgBMAFAEYCMgJQwA9Mow5SmCjVpA

Even with TS 5.3.0-beta its type is not defined in TypeScript.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `toSpliced`, you need to set [`target` to `ESNext`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=5.3.0-beta#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gcgB6YDQyYCe+hAXpgLoCwAUKJLIggEyrxIB0UIAygA4AbAJbAApgBMAFAEYCMgJQwA9Mow5SmCjVpA) (for now, until there's an `ES2023` setting). Your playground targets `ES2017`, which wouldn't support `toSpliced` or anything else from ES2018 onward. You also need to be using a fairly recent version of TypeScript (for instance, [5.1.6 doesn't support it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=5.1.6#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gcgB6YDQyYCe+hAXpgLoCwAUKJLIggEyrxIB0UIAygA4AbAJbAApgBMAFAEYCMgJQwA9Mow5SmCjVpA), but [5.2.2 does](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=5.2.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gcgB6YDQyYCe+hAXpgLoCwAUKJLIggEyrxIB0UIAygA4AbAJbAApgBMAFAEYCMgJQwA9Mow5SmCjVpA); I don't know precisely where in there it was added).

Answer (score 1):

The definitions for these methods were added as part of [Typescript 5.2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-2/#copying-array-methods). Besides setting the `target` in your tsconfig, you can instead add `"ES2023"` or just `"ES2023.Array"` to the `lib`.